# Swift protocol nested in a class

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I would like to nest a protocol in my class to implement the delegate pattern like so :

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    protocol Delegate {
        func eventHappened()
    }

    var delegate:MyViewController.Delegate?

    private func myFunc() {
        delegate?.eventHappened()
    }
}
```

But the compiler will not allow it :

> Protocol 'Delegate' cannot be nested inside another declaration

I can easily make it work by declaring `MyViewControllerDelegate` outside of the class scope.
My question is *why* such a limitation ?

Comment: This was also discussed on Apple Developer Forums : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15195

Answer (score 25):

according to the [swift documenation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/NestedTypes.html)

> Swift enables you to define nested types, whereby you nest supporting enumerations, classes, and structures within the definition of the type they support.

Given protocols are not on that list, it doesn't appear that it's currently supported.
It's possible they will add the feature at some point, (Swift was announced less than 2 years go after all). Any idea on why they won't or haven't would be speculation on my part.

Answer (score 10):

this is my work around:

```
protocol MyViewControllerDelegate : class {
    func eventHappened()
}

class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    typealias Delegate = MyViewControllerDelegate
    weak var delegate: Delegate?
    
    private func myFunc() {
        delegate?.eventHappened()
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like a workaround to me, rather it is the only possible way ))

Answer (score -7):

A separate problem with your class is that `delegate` does not have a concrete type.  You can get away with declaring it a `MyViewController.Delegate?` because it is an optional type and can be `.None`. But that just makes your private `myFunc` dead code.  Only enumerations, classes, and structures can **conform** to a protocol. Which of those three types is `delegate`?

That said, this is not the cause of your problem. When I make a real type for `delegate` and make it conform to the `Delegate` protocol, I still get the same error.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

  protocol Delegate {
    func eventHappened()
  }

  class Classy: Delegate {
    func eventHappened() {
      print("eventHappened")
    }
  }

  var delegate: Classy? = Classy()

  func myFunc() {
    delegate?.eventHappened()
  }
}
```

[image]

As an esoteric exercise this might be interesting in pushing the bounds of what a class might do but no one should every try to declare a protocol inside of a class.  Protocols are all about type composition and collections. There is no code reuse scenario when you are limited to being in the same outer class.

Comment: Delegate protocols are intended to be implemented by the users of this class.  What you're describing as a problem isn't a problem— it's an essential software design pattern used throughout Apple's Cocoa & CocoaTouch frameworks.

Comment: You can get a full overview of how delegates are intended to be used in Cocoa _(and by extension, Objective-C & Swift, since the former was designed in tandem with Cocoa and the latter primarily for Cocoa apps)_ in Apple's [Cocoa Core Competencies guide, Delegation section](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH14-SW1).